# Property not found hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Iam new to hibernate , While i was trying to do a simple work like fetch data from database and display it.

**DummyController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DummyController {

TestHelper helper;
DataModel  model;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of DummyController
 */
public DummyController() {
    helper = new TestHelper();
}

public DataModel getDummys()
{
    if(model == null)
    {
        model =  new ListDataModel(helper.getNames());
    }
   return model;
}

}
```

**Dummy.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dummy")
public class Dummy  implements java.io.Serializable {


private Short id;
private String name;

public Dummy() {
}

public Dummy(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}
/**
 * get the id from dummy 
 * @return
 */
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "identity")
@GenericGenerator(name = "identity", strategy = "identity")
@Column(name = "ID")
@Transient
public Short getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Short id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "Name", length = 500)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

The problem is below

```
<h:dataTable value="#{dummyController.dummys}" var="dummydata" border="0"    
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" 
style="border:solid 1px">
        <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                 <h:outputText value="#{dummydata.Id}"/>
               </h:column>
               <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                 <h:outputText value="Names"/>
                 <h:outputText value="#{dummydata.Name}"/>
               </f:facet>

       </h:column>  
 </h:dataTable>
```

Here iam unablkle to access `dummydata.Name` and `dummydata.Id` its not showing in suggestions and throwing property not found if i run.

Comment: What does the `TestHelper.getNames` method look like?

Comment: Your dummydata is of type DataModel. But your are trying to get dummydata.Name & dummydata.Id so i will bot work. If you dummyData is of type Dummy then it would match.

Comment: @Jay So what would i do, can i return List<Dummy> instead of DataModel

Comment: Yes that would match.

Comment: Thanks Jay , you can post a answer , i will accept that for sure, It was my mistake , i just thought datamodel is what xhtml will look for.